# Java - mouseMoved() event handling in Swing

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, mouseevent, mouse-listeners

I want to listen for mouse movements and clicks in my JFrame. To do this, I've added a MouseListener implemented like this: (whole code of View class is at https://gist.github.com/2837224, Board class is at https://gist.github.com/2837231)

```
class BattleshipsFrame extends JFrame {
  private final Board playerBoard, opponentBoard;
  private View view;

/** Main window constructor. */
BattleshipsFrame() {
  ...
  ...   
  ...
  //creating and displaying boards
  playerBoard = new Board();
  opponentBoard = new Board();
  PlayerBoardListener mouseListener = new PlayerBoardListener();
  this.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
  playerBoard.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
  opponentBoard.addMouseListener(new OpponentBoardListener());
  boards.add(playerBoard);
  boards.add(opponentBoard);
  ...
  ...
  ...
}

/** Listener responsible for handling mouse events on player board */
private class PlayerBoardListener extends MouseAdapter {
  @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    try {
      if(event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && controllerConnection != null)
        controllerConnection.sendShipPlacedEvent(event.getX()/40, event.getY()/40, ShipType.EMPTY);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }   
  @Override public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
    //TODO
    System.out.println("Mouse movement detected! Actual mouse position is: " + event.getX()+ "," + event.getY() + ".");
  }   
  @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    //TODO
    System.out.println("Mouse movement detected! Actual mouse position is: " + event.getX()+ "," + event.getY() + ".");
  }   

}
```

Funny thing is that mousePressed() is working well, but the other two are not (nothing shows on console while moving the mouse). Anybody could tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: nothing better post here and SSCCE not link somewhere to universum, that about future readers,

Comment: Thanks for interesting link. Working example will be too long in my opinion, I've posted whole code in links on top.

Comment: A well-made working example would be short in fact. For simple questions you likely won't need this, but for complex questions, it is something that we ourselves would likely have to make to help solve, so it's better if you make it for us. Luck.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to receive `mouseMoved` and `mouseDragged` events, you need to also register your listener as a [`MouseMotionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html).

```
MouseAdapter adapter = ...
JFrame frame = ...
frame.addMouseListener(adapter);
frame.addMouseMotionListener(adapter);
```

Comment: It worked! I should read documentation more carefully next time. However - thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try implementing `MouseMotionListener` and with  `MouseListener` too ?

Comment: I've tried this already, and it's the same thing, as MouseAdapter implements both MouseMotionListener and MouseListener. The solution is on top already. ;-)